# problem with composite function

Tags: calculus, functions

This morning I was solving a little exercise that read as the following:

Given a function $u(x)$ for which we define an operator $\hat{u}$ as, for any function $f(x)$ over **R**, $\hat{u}(f(x))=f(u(x))$.

We were asked to search for some values one of which required $\hat{u}(\dfrac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x})$. Now I don't know whether the latter is equal to $\dfrac{\partial f(u)}{\partial x}$ or to $\dfrac{\partial f(u)}{\partial u}$. I feel it has to the first one but I'm not sure. Can anyone tell me the right answer with justification please ?

Answer (score 0):

By the definition:

$$
\hat u\left( \frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x}\right)= \frac{\partial f(u(x))}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial f(u(x))}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u(x)}{\partial x}
$$